# How to have a turtle choose max-one-of from nearby turtles?

Tags: netlogo

The situation is very simple: there are some turtles, producers, and others, choosers. Producers produce something with a certain objective-quality, choosers choose on the basis on perceived quality.

Choosers should be able to choose only from producers in Moore Neighbour, and can choose **only one** producer.
Once chosen, they create a local for the chosen producer.

Here is what I have to begin with:

```py
ask turtles with [group = "choosers"] [
    let friends turtles-on neighbors
    let x friends with-max [perceived-quality]
    ask x [set chosen? (true) ]
  ]
```

Of course, with this code turtles choose all those with max perceived-quality (>1).

If I use max-one-of, there is an error, because not all the turtles have “friends”.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-one-of` indeed always expects there to be at least 1 option to choose from. An easy way to work around it is to first check if there is an option to choose from before trying to choose one.

```
ask turtles with [any? turtles-on neighbors] [
    ask max-one-of turtles-on neighbors perceived-quality [...]
]
```